# How to test behaviour of user`s click on the <Link .../> element from React-router v6 with React Testing Library?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-testing-library

i want to test click bahaviour when user's click on a  element from **'react-router-dom' v6**; I have tried a lot of different variants, but no one didn't work =( The main problem is: linter says, what click event doesn't execute, location doesn`t changed and so on...

Main file:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <LangContextProvider>
          <App />
        </LangContextProvider>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Routes:

```
<Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<MainLayout />}>
      {/* TODO Переделать тут роутинг */}
      <Route index element={<MainPage />} />
      <Route path="main" element={<MainPage />}>
        <Route path="auth" element={<AuthFormComponent />} />
        <Route path="page-not-found" element={<NotFoundPage />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="page-not-found" replace />} />
      </Route>
....
```

Component for testing:

```
const FooterComponent = () => {

  return (
    <div className={cn(style.container)} data-testid="footer-component">
      <div className={cn(style.upper)}>
        <div className={style.svgContainer}>
          <CloverSvg />
        </div>
        <div className={cn(style.tutotarial)}>
          <ul>
            <li><h3>Начать</h3></li>
            <li onClick={() => scrollToElementIdHandler("hero")}>Давайте приступим</li>
            <li onClick={() => scrollToElementIdHandler("hero")}>Мобильное приложение</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div className={cn(style.links)}>
          <ul>
            <li><h3>О проекте</h3></li>
            <li><Link to={"/faq"}>FAQ</Link></li>
            <li>
              <Link to={"/term-of-use"}>Пользовательское соглашение</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to={"/privacy-policy"} data-testid="privacy-policy-link">Политика конфиденциальности</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className={cn(style.bottom)}>
        <ul>
          <li>Домой</li>
          <li>Особенности</li>
          <li>Галерея</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li>Контакты</li>
          <li>О разработке</li>
          <li>Отзывы</li>
        </ul>
        <div className={style.social}>
          <div><i className="fab fa-telegram"></i></div>
          <div><i className="fab fa-vk"></i></div>
          <div><i className="fab fa-instagram"></i></div>
          <div><i className="fab fa-facebook"></i></div>
          <div><i className="fab fa-blogger"></i></div>
        </div>
        <div className={cn(style.time)}>
          <p>© 2021–{new Date().getFullYear()}, Memorush, официальный сайт</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default FooterComponent;
```

My test:

```
  it("should change current location", async () => {
    const history = createBrowserHistory();

    // mock push function
    history.push = jest.fn();

    render(<BrowserRouter><FooterComponent/></BrowserRouter>);

    await fireEvent.click(screen.getByTestId(/privacy-policy-link/i));

    expect(history.location.pathname).toBe(/privacy-policy/i);
  });
```

One more test:

```
  it("should change current location", async () => {
    const history = createMemoryHistory();

    // mock push function
    history.push = jest.fn();

    render(<BrowserRouter><FooterComponent/></BrowserRouter>);

    await fireEvent.click(screen.getByTestId(/privacy-policy-link/i));

    expect(history.push).toHaveBeenCalledWith(/privacy-policy/i);
  });
```

Comment: It's unclear why you are unit testing code you don't own (*i.e. router/link/history object/etc*), but in your test cases you are not using the correct history object. The `BrowserRouter` and `MemoryRouters` each maintain their own internal `history` object reference. Your `history` object isn't used. Additionally, the `Link` component doesn't use `history.push` even as an implementation detail, it renders an anchor `<a>` tag to the DOM. A more correct testing paradigm would be to click the link, wait for the UI update, and assert that *some* "privacy policy" UI is now being rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this test, but I'm not sure that it's the optimal way, but we can test our functionality:

```
it("should change location", async () => {

    const Application = (
      <MemoryRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<div><Outlet /></div>} >
            <Route index element={<FooterComponent />} />
            <Route path="privacy-policy" element={<h1 data-testid="privacy-page">Privacy Page</h1>} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </MemoryRouter>
    );

    render(Application);
    await userEvent.click(screen.getByTestId("privacy-policy-link"));
    expect(screen.getByTestId(/privacy-page/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
  })
```